# Evaluating interaction effects with contrasts

Tags: r, interaction, lsmeans, generalized-least-squares

I need help to interpret and understand contrasts of interaction effects for one of my models.

I have a gls model with an interaction effect as follows:

```
mod<-gls(Y~ A*B, dat, weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | A * B))
```

When I run anova I get a significant interaction effect as follows:

```
> Anova(mod) # Analysis of variance gls
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: Y
                Df   Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
A                2  34.732  2.871e-08 ***
B                2 106.325  < 2.2e-16 ***
A:B              4  18.116   0.001171 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
```

Then I'm doing multiple comparisons :

```
> multcomp::cld(emmeans(mod, ~A*B),
+               Letters = letters, reversed = T) # Post-Hoc test lm
 A          B                emmean SE  df   lower.CL upper.CL .group
 Low         Metabolite       92.3 4.63 249     83.2    101.5  a    
 Low         Normal           66.9 4.97 249     57.1     76.7   b   
 Normal      Metabolite       61.4 4.79 249     52.0     70.9   bc  
 Metabolite  Metabolite       61.4 4.01 249     53.5     69.3   bc  
 Normal      Normal           45.5 4.79 249     36.0     54.9   bcd 
 Normal      Low              42.0 4.88 249     32.4     51.6    cd 
 Metabolite  Normal           38.9 4.97 249     29.1     48.7     d 
 Low         Low              35.3 5.29 249     24.9     45.7     d 
 Metabolite  Low              28.0 4.63 249     18.9     37.1     d 

Confidence level used: 0.95 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 9 estimates 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
NOTE: If two or more means share the same grouping symbol,
      then we cannot show them to be different.
      But we also did not show them to be the same.
```

However, If I'm interested in how the interaction effects, my understanding is that I need to basically do contrasts of contrasts accordingly:

```
emm_mod<- emmeans(mod, ~A*B) # look at contrasts
```

Then:

```
> contrast(emm_mod, interaction = "pairwise")
 A pairwise        B pairwise             estimate  SE    df t.ratio p.value
 Metabolite - Normal Metabolite - Normal    6.56 10.17  84.4   0.646  0.5203
 Metabolite - Low  Metabolite - Normal     -2.95  9.22 109.8  -0.320  0.7495
 Normal - Low   Metabolite - Normal        -9.51 10.69  88.8  -0.890  0.3758
 Metabolite - Normal Metabolite - Low      14.03 10.01  80.7   1.401  0.1650
 Metabolite - Low  Metabolite - Low       -23.58  8.41 108.9  -2.803  0.0060
 Normal - Low   Metabolite - Low          -37.61 10.44  84.7  -3.604  0.0005
 Metabolite - Normal Normal - Low           7.47  7.58  99.4   0.986  0.3267
 Metabolite - Low  Normal - Low           -20.62  8.28  84.6  -2.492  0.0147
 Normal - Low   Normal - Low              -28.09  8.87  94.5  -3.168  0.0021

Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite
```

What I'm now wondering is how to interpret this table and what to report. I've seen a lot of research papers where they just mention that there's an interaction effect (From ANOVA output) and then they basically stop there and don't go any further. I therefore thought of doing the contrasts of contrasts and test the interactions and add this in supplementary. If I'm understanding it correctly, the first output line in the last code says:

Theres no significant difference between Metabolite and Normal (B) within Metabolite (A) compared to etabolite and Normal (B) within Normal (A) ?

But how do you interpret if the interaction effect is positive or negative?
My guess, looking at the estimates but what are they in relation to? Some are positive and some are negative, compared to what? Is this right?

I also add a figure for clarity and visualization:

```
plot(
  ggpredict(mod, terms = c("B", "A"))
)
```

[image]

Comment: The figure seems to describe your results pretty well. I have trouble understanding interaction contrasts. I suggest that you add the `lsmeans` tag to the question, to try to draw attention from someone who understands `emmeans` better than either of us.

Comment: The estimates are differences of differences, e.g., the first one is `(A=Metabolite - A=Normal|B = Metabolite) - (A=Metabolite - A=Normal|B = Normal)`.  I usually use `"consec"` rather than `"pairwise"` so you just get the minimum number of interaction contrasts. You can always look at `coef(contrast(...))` if you get confused.